# Set Sub-Stage value based on Opportunity Stage

Tags: workflow, opportunity, workflowrule

I need to set the Sub-Stage value (from a picklist) once the Opportunity Stage is set to a specific value.  Can this be done as a formula or workflow or does not need to have code written to do so?

Comment: Assuming your Sub-Stage is a picklist too, have you looked at [dependent picklists](https://help.salesforce.com/articleView?id=fields_defining_field_dependencies.htm&type=5)?

Comment: If you use a formula, the substage can't be edited on the form

Comment: We don't want the user to edit the field. It will not even be visible.

Comment: Yes the Sub-Stage is a picklist.  If I use a Dependent picklist, and there is only one value, does that value automatically get populated or does the user still need to select it?  This needs to be a completely automated process, which is why I lean toward the formula solution.